# Return type of getId() on a thread object

Tags: java

Why does, for example, `Thread.currentThread().getId()` return a long?

Does this really need to be 64 bits? Like I'm going to ever have a machine running that number of threads!

Seriously, it's a bit of a pain since I'm writing something that keeps a track of thread identifiers along with other bits and I'd really rather not have to use such a long number, else the unique key I have to generate is enormous.

Perhaps there is a convention on the long return; like the first 48 bits are always zero. I had a dig about on the internet but didn't find anything. I hope so; does anyone know for sure?

Thanks.

Comment: No. getId() will probably return some identifier of the underlying operating system, so you have exactly zero guarantees on the value.

Comment: It seems like good idea to plan for the future and allow for a really big number of threads.

Comment: Because that's the way they designed it. You've overlooked the case where it really returns a 64-bit *pointer*. Not constructive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code:

```
private static synchronized long nextThreadID() {
    return ++threadSeqNumber;
}
```

should give insight as to why.  Essentially thread ids are assigned by a running counter, so if you don't terminate your JVM for a significant amount of time, this number would go above the long.  I can only imagine that they did it to reduce the chance for collisions in long running threads.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation +1 and accept in a few minutes. Am I alone here in thinking that's a little vulgar?

Comment: @Bathsheba my answer is vulgar?

Comment: No, it's perfect. The concept of just making a number so big that we don't have to worry about the bug is vulgar, imo.

Comment: @Bathsheba ah ok.  Yeah I can see that.  I suppose it was akin to just generating GUIDs that are only valid until the JVM terminates.

Comment: Point is, there are so many overheads in creating threads, why didn't the designers allow the nextThreadID() implementation to take a little longer over its choice of number to return. Identifiers could have been released back to a pool once threads terminate; surely?

Comment: @Bathsheba - do a back of the napkin calculation - if from the start of the JVM 10,000 threads are created every minute and the JVM is never shut down for the next 100 years, even then you will not reach the long max value - why bother with a pool and stuff?

Answer (score 1):

Java applications are sand-boxed relative to other Java applications, which is way thread ID's are even likely to collide.

Threads are not meant to be unique across all application, they are only unique per application. Looking at the `Thread.init` method in the source, you can find:

```
private static synchronized long nextThreadID() {
    return ++threadSeqNumber;
}

/* For generating thread ID */
private static long threadSeqNumber;
```

I guess it's used to prevent a potential overflow bug. As threads get created, the number would eventually overflow. Long is just being

```
9223372036854775807(Max long value) - 2147483647(Max int value) = 9.223372e+18
```

a bit more safe:)